# Transit Visa for Canadian Passport Holder

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, transit-visas, canadian-citizens

I am a Canadian travelling to Canada from India Via. Brussels. There is a layover time of ~ 3 hours and 45 minutes in Brussels on the same day. My travel is from Mumbai (India) - Brussels - Toronto (Canada)

Do I need to get a Transit Visa?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Canadians do not require visas to enter the Schengen zone.

[Link to official document from The European Commission](http://ec.europa.eu/immigration/do-i-need-a-visa/do-i-need-a-short-stay-visa_en#novisa)

Click on 'Countries whose citizens do not require visas to enter the Schengen area'. Canada is on there.